# Docker command gives me error: could not find `Cargo.toml` in `/contract` or any parent directory. I think this is from a faulty docker command

Tags: docker, rust, webassembly, rust-cargo

I am trying to run a contract optimizer for my Secret Network app code. I am pretty sure that this error has nothing to do with Secret Network so that's not relevant. All you need to know is that my app is written in rust. I am 99% sure my problem is the fault of a bad docker command. I am running this command in the same directory of my app's code.

```
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/contract \
  --mount type=volume,source="$(basename "$(pwd)")_cache",target=/code/target \
  --mount type=volume,source=registry_cache,target=/usr/local/cargo/registry \
  enigmampc/secret-contract-optimizer
```

I put the above docker command into a script and ran it. I got this in my terminal:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: 'C:/Program Files/Git/code/target' mount path must be absolute.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I tried to modify the command by adding an extra `/` to the start of the `target` value like this:

```
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/contract \
  --mount type=volume,source="$(basename "$(pwd)")_cache",target=//code/target \
  --mount type=volume,source=registry_cache,target=//usr/local/cargo/registry \
  enigmampc/secret-contract-optimizer
```

But then I got this error:

```
error: could not find `Cargo.toml` in `/contract` or any parent directory
```

So what is wrong with the docker command? I am running it in the same directory as the `Cargo.toml` file for my app.

Comment: Are you running on Windows? I think `$(pwd)` (and others) won't work on Windows. You'll need to find the Windows equivalents.

Comment: Yes, I am running Windows. I'm still using bash though (Cmder). What's the pwd equivalent for a bash terminal in Windows?

Comment: I just ran `echo $(pwd)` in my cmder bash terminal and it worked. It output `/c/Users/<MY USER NAME>/path/to/current/dir`